# How to set a variable to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

Here is a dictionary (You don't need to understand what it says to answer the problem):

> Long_Swordsmenc={'as': 4, 'ar': 5, 'de': 2, 'co': 2, 'asr': 7, 'he': 10, 'wm': 1, 'am': 1}

Next, I ask the user to choose a unit:

> x1=raw_input('Player 1, enter your unit: ')

Then, when the user inputs 'Long_Swordsmenc', x1 will equal 'Long_Swordsmenc'.
When I type:

> Print x1

I want this to pop up:

> {'as': 4, 'ar': 5, 'de': 2, 'co': 2, 'asr': 7, 'he': 10, 'wm': 1, 'am': 1}

Comment: You told us what you want, but you should add what you have tried and what actually happens. How is `Print` defined? or do you mean `print`?

Comment: If someone gives you good answers, accept and / or upvote the helpful ones. At the moment, none of your questions has an accepted answer.

Comment: Please don't just [delete and then repost your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001817/how-to-make-a-variable-equal-to-a-dictionary-in-python). Edit them to add details or clarify; that will bump them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely want a dictionary of dictionaries, instead of just storing the variable `Long_Swordsmenc`. So:

```
weapons = {}
weapons['Long_Swordsmenc'] = {'as': 4, 'ar': 5, 'de': 2, 'co': 2, 'asr': 7, 'he': 10, 'wm': 1, 'am': 1}

x1=raw_input('Player 1, enter your unit: ')
```

Then:

```
>>> print weapons[x1]
{'as': 4, 'ar': 5, 'de': 2, 'co': 2, 'asr': 7, 'he': 10, 'wm': 1, 'am': 1}
```

You could also access `globals()`, but it's much better practice (and probably safer), to limit to keys of a dict

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to use a nested dictionary, where `'Long_Swordsmenc'` is one of the keys.  For example:

```
units = {'Long_Swordsmenc': {'as': 4, 'ar': 5, 'de': 2, 'co': 2,
                             'asr': 7, 'he': 10, 'wm': 1, 'am': 1}}
x1 = raw_input('Player 1, enter your unit: ')
print units[x1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: the best way to do this is a dictionary like other answers suggest. However, here is to actually do what you requested.

If you don't put your `Long_Swordsmenc` variable into a dictionary like the other answers suggest, you'd have to do this:

```
import sys

module = sys.modules[__name__]

Long_Swordsmenc = {'as': 4, 'ar': 5, 'de': 2, 'co': 2, 'asr': 7, 'he': 10, 'wm': 1, 'am': 1}

x1 = raw_input('Player 1, enter your unit: ')
unit1 = getattr(module, x1)

print(unit1)
```

Prints:

```
{'as': 4, 'ar': 5, 'de': 2, 'co': 2, 'asr': 7, 'he': 10, 'wm': 1, 'am': 1}
```

EDIT: An easier method is to use `globals()[x1]` like @martineau and @mhlester suggested. See the comments below for more information.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `unit1 = globals()[x1]` and dispense with all the `module` & `getattr()` fluff?

Comment: @martineau Yeah, good point. ``globals()`` is a better option.

Comment: I'll up-vote anyway, for at least answering the question almost sans advice.

Comment: I added a note on using ``globals()``.